# ROS nodes for aerial vehicle localization

Tags: control, imu, gps, camera, localilzation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

I'm developing an aerial vehicle which is equipped with a GPS, IMU and bottom camera (pointed at the ground for target tracking).
I was looking for a way to fuse the data, with two objectives:

- Obtaining a coordinate for the "drone" localization (I could assume it starts at (0,0))
- Extrating a position of the detected targets (on the "local coordinate system" and GPS information)

Which nodes will prove useful for this application?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205787/ros-nodes-for-aerial-vehicle-localization/) by [nvoltex](https://answers.ros.org/users/3575/nvoltex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2015-03-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) may be what you are looking for.

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2015-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nvoltex](https://answers.ros.org/users/3575/nvoltex/) on 2015-04-07**:
Thanks for the help! That seems to be what I need, but does it work with only GPS and IMU?

**Comment by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) on 2015-04-07**:
On the [ROS wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) for robot_localization you can see an image showing that you can also use a camera and a 3D sensing device, provided that you extract the necessary information from them. For the camera you may use something like viso2_ros package.

**Comment by [nvoltex](https://answers.ros.org/users/3575/nvoltex/) on 2015-04-08**:
Does that mean that the GPS combined with the IMU is not enough?
Another question: The IMU data used by robot_localization needs the pose? or only the raw data (linear accelaration and angular velocity)?